# Check presence of an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which i need to check the presence of a HTML element dynamically.Therefore I need to know the correct way of doing this

Comment: is if(document.getElementById("id")) correct

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(function() {
  if ($('.myElement').length > 0) {
    console.log('There is one or more elements with class="myElement"');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id').length === 0; // element does not exist 
$('#id').length > 0; // element exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like very much the "presence" idiom from Ruby on Rails, so I have added this to my JS set up:

```js
jQuery.fn.presence = function presence() {
    return this.length !== 0 ? this : null;
};
```

and now use this in my code:

```
if (el.presence()) { ... }
```

and better yet

```
const ul = el.parents('UL').first().presence() ?? el.siblings('UL').first()
```

(If you can't afford `??`, `||` would do just as well here.)